# Can you explain the crawling ritual in Breaking Bad season 3 episode 1

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

What is the meaning of the crawling ritual in Breaking Bad season 3 episode 1. It takes place right at the beginning of episode 1. Several farmers in a Mexican village are crawling towards some kind of shrine, decorated with flowers. The twin killers arrive in the Mercedes and join the crawling.

Presumably this is a religious ritual, but what is their religion?